# Send multiple checkbox array to email

Tags: php

I am creating a contact form which has radio button, checkbox and text-area field. When I hit submit button I get all the values in my email EXCEPT checkbox. Attached below is my PHP and HTML snippet,,Kindly assist?

```
<?php

//INITIALIZE VARIABLES and set to empty values
$checkbox = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {   

    // Check the values from checkbox and POST them to email
    if(!empty($_POST["checkbox"]))                         //check if the user has selected a CHECKBOX or NOT 
         {
         $checkbox =$_POST["checkbox"];                //Array of values from the checkbox

         foreach($checkbox as $value)             //loop to store and display values of individual checkboxes 
         {echo $value;}}                           //Display selected checkbox
        else {test_input($_POST["value"]);}      //POST values to email

//HTML CODE

What project would you like for your business venture? <span class= "error"> * </span>
<br> <br> <input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Graphics Design"> Graphics Design (Book, Posters, Flyers, Banners, Magazines, T-Shirts) <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Logo Design"> Professional logo Design <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Branding"> Branding <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Digital Marketing" > Digital Marketing (Social-Media Marketing, E-Mail Marketing & SEO)

<button class="submit" type= "reset" value= "Reset"> Reset Form </button>
<button class="submit" type= "submit" value= "Submit"> Submit  Form </button>
```

Comment: Checkboxes are only sent when checked.

Comment: To which function you are sending value for email, share that also, at least 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

if($_POST["email"]){
$ToEmail = 'required email ID';
$EmailSubject = 'Request from contactus page';
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"];
$MESSAGE_BODY = ' Contact from : '.$firstname.' '.$lastname."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .='Email : '.$email."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .='Message : '.$message."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= 'Interested in :'."\r\n";
if (isset($_POST['checkbox-name']) && !empty($_POST['checkbox-name']))        {
foreach($_POST['checkbox-name'] as $selected ){
$MESSAGE_BODY .= $selected."\r\n";
}
}
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die     ("Failure");
echo "Your message was sent";
}
else{
echo "SOrry , No mail was sent";
}
?>
```